# How to "unload" native library in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono

I can load native library like `JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("my_library")` and then call it's functions.
How can I "unload" or "dispose" loaded library after use? And should I really have to do this? Is there a "lifecycle" of loaded library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a "lifecycle" of loaded library?

Yes, In Java it is based on the "classloader" that performed the `LoadLibrary`.

So assuming that you are loading the shared lib within a class named `X`, when the instance of `X` that loaded the library is garbaged collected, the shared library is also dropped/cleared from memory as there is nothing referencing it.

Note: Remember that if you are loading this within the Java runtime that is hosted by Xamarin/Mono, and thus you might have **.Net/Java peer objects** and for Java to GC that loaderclass, its .Net peer object needs to be released (disposed).

> And should I really have to do this?

Assuming your code is not leaking either of the peer objects, the Java runtime will clear the memory allocated to your shared library when it is able.

Note: If the usage if your shared library functions is limited, I would recommend that you isolate your `LoadLibrary` with its own C#/Java.Lang.Object class and not use it within the App's Application subclass, or an Activity's subclass so you can control its lifecycle directly.

In terms of performance, remember there is a penalty for loading that shared library, so if your apps usage pattern dictates, you might want to hold a reference to that classloader instead of allowing it to be GC'd all the time, i.e. speed of access vs. memory consumption, but only you can make that determination based upon profiling the app.